# locate home directories of deleted users in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to locate home directories of users long since deleted, that have nothing but their profile files (.bashrc, .bash_logout, .profile, etc....) still left in.

I tried
`find . -type d -empty -print`

but it only finds truly empty directories with active users.  I need those directories that have no users, plus I don't care about hidden files.  I only care if the folders have actual user files in it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should compare the list of folder in the home directory against the user accounts in `/etc/passwd`. That should be much more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` has an option that might come in handy in this case: `-nouser`. It matches with files that have a (numeric) user id that corresponds to no user as specified in `/etc/passwd`. So for example, the following command will print all directories under `/home` that are not owned by a current user:

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -nouser
```

**Edit**: If you only want to print the directories that have no non-hidden files, you can amend the above as follows:

```
find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -nouser -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
        (($(ls "$dir" | wc -l) == 0)) && echo $dir
    done
```

Comment: thanks much.   how do I separate empty (except .files) vs non-empty (regular files and folders)

Comment: Why would you want to? Sounds like simply `-nouser` would accomplish what you want.

Comment: No no no, don't use `ls` in scripts. You can do this in pure `find` - look for non-dot files and `-prune` is there is a match. Maybe you have to run a second `find` on each drectory, though.

Comment: @tripleee That's an interesting idea, but can you do it with a single `find`? If not, it's no better that the `ls` solution.

Comment: Not in a place where I can test, but vaguely thinking GNU `find` with a combnation of `-printf` and `-prune` would work.

Comment: HI all, thanks much.  This answer did work for me, but I am interested in the single line version if you do get any time to do so.  If not, do not worry, My question was answered.  Thanks again.